# Setting password expiration settings on CentOS

Tags: centos, redhat, password-management

How does one set the password expiration parameters on CentOS or Red Hat Linux using PAM?  Specifically, I need to set the following:

1. Maximum number of days that a password may be used.
2. Minimum number of days allowed between password changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file that will do this: `/etc/login.defs`. Two values you want to look to change here:

- PASS_MAX_DAYS
- PASS_MIN_DAYS

Answer (score 0):

the parameters you are searching for are:
`PAM_MAX_DAYS`
`PAM_MIN_DAYS`

you'll find a more detailed explanation and some other hints [here](http://www.puschitz.com/SecuringLinux.shtml#EnablingPasswordAging).